dynamic proxy in puppeteer
I'm wondering if there is a way to do dynamic proxying with Puppeteer. For example, on my local I can set up my network to use a .pac file.
The problem I am trying to solve is that I only want my proxy to handle network requests from a few whitelisted domains.
I see that there are options like HTTP_PROXY but this is global with no filtering. I can only see that there is a proxyBypassList but that is more of a blacklist and I need a whitelist.
I looked through the docs
